# Why my RecyclerView is not filled with data from retrofit?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, retrofit

I have a trouble with my recyclerview. I get the list using retrofit, i acquire all the data, as shown in logs:

```
D/OkHttp: {"data":[{"user_profile_id":45,"recipe_id":1,"title":"earum","category":"dessert","tags":["vegetarian","family","fast-food","on-hot","advanced"],"photos":[],"likes":{"logged_user_liked":false,"likes_count":0}},{"user_profile_id":23,"recipe_id":2,"title":"nisi","category":"additives","tags":["for-party","for-beginners","for-beginners","fast-food","advanced"],"photos":[],"likes":{"logged_user_liked":false,"likes_count":4}},{"user_profile_id":31,"recipe_id":3,"title":"asperiores","category":"soup","tags":["healthy","fast-food","advanced","for-diabetics","vegetable"],"photos":[],"likes":{"logged_user_liked":false,"likes_count":2}},{"user_profile_id":24,"recipe_id":4,"title":"vitae","category":"breakfast","tags":["caloric","healthy","caloric","with-meat","cold"],"photos":[],"likes":{"logged_user_liked":false,"likes_count":0}},{"user_profile_id":16,"recipe_id":5,"title":"odit","category":"salads","tags":["for-party","for-party","vegetable","cold","for-diabetics"],"photos":[],"likes":{"logged_user_liked":false,"likes_count":2}},{"user_profile_id":5,"recipe_id":6,"title":"vero","category":"drink","tags":["no-salt","family","with-meat","for-beginners","cold"],"photos":[],"likes":{"logged_user_liked":false,"likes_count":2}},{"user_profile_id":16,"recipe_id":7,"title":"quisquam","category":"dessert","tags":["healthy","family","caloric","on-hot","on-hot"],"photos":[],"likes":{"logged_user_liked":false,"likes_count":1}},{"user_profile_id":36,"recipe_id":8,"title":"sit","category":"snacks","tags":["little-fat","cold","little-fat","vegetarian","with-meat"],"photos":[],"likes":{"logged_user_liked":false,"likes_count":0}},{"user_profile_id":33,"recipe_id":9,"title":"sed","category":"salads","tags":["cold","with-meat","for-party","caloric","advanced"],"photos":[],"likes":{"logged_user_liked":false,"likes_count":4}},{"user_profile_id":44,"recipe_id":10,"title":"enim","category":"main-course","tags":["family","on-hot","healthy","cold","advanced"],"photos":[],"likes":{"logged_user_liked":false,"likes_count":0}},{"user_profile_id":25,"recipe_id":11,"title":"soluta","category":"breakfast","tags":["with-meat","no-salt","no-salt","fast-food","vegetable"],"photos":[],"likes":{"logged_user_liked":false,"likes_count":1}},{"user_profile_id":9,"recipe_id":12,"title":"eius","category":"main-course","tags":["family","caloric","on-hot","for-diabetics","fast-food"],"photos":[],"likes":{"logged_user_liked":false,"likes_count":3}},{"user_profile_id":40,"recipe_id":13,"title":"neque","category":"main-course","tags":["healthy","vegetarian","for-diabetics","no-salt","for-party"],"photos":[],"likes":{"logged_user_liked":false,"likes_count":3}},{"user_profile_id":38,"recipe_id":14,"title":"atque","category":"snacks","tags":["caloric","no-salt","cold","fast-food","healthy"],"photos":[],"likes":{"logged_user_liked":false,"likes_count":0}},{"user_profile_id":19,"recipe_id":15,"title":"atque","category":"preserves","tags":["family","fast-food","vegetarian","vegetarian","caloric"],"photos":[],"likes":{"logged_user_liked":false,"likes_count":2}}],"pagination":{"total":50,"count":15,"per_page":15,"current_page":1,"total_pages":4}}
    <-- END HTTP (3140-byte body)
    I/System.out: something wrong happend
```

what is weird, with data, i also get onFailure response and my recyclerview is not filled with data.

Here is the code of my retrofit call:

```
RetrofitClient.instance.fetchAllRecipes().enqueue(object: Callback<List<DataRecipes>> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<List<DataRecipes>>,
                response: Response<List<DataRecipes>>
            ) {
                response.body()?.let {
                    recipesList = it
                }
                tasksRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
                recipesAdapter = RecipesAdapter(recipesList)
                tasksRecyclerView.adapter = recipesAdapter
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<DataRecipes>>, t: Throwable) {
                println("something wrong happened")
            }

        })
```

and from the adapter:

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecipesViewHolder {
        return RecipesViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.recipe_cardview,parent,false))
    }

    inner class RecipesViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        val title: TextView
        val category : TextView
        val tags : TextView
        val photo : ImageView
//
        init{
            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TitleTV)
            category = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Categories)
            tags = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tags)
            photo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Recipe_photo)
        }

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecipesViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = listOfRecipes[position]
        holder.itemView.apply {
            holder.title.text = item.data.title
            holder.category.text = item.data.category
            holder.tags.text = item.data.tags.toString()
            Picasso.get()
                .load(item.data.photos?.data?.url)
                .into(holder.photo)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return listOfRecipes.size
    }

}
```

Do you have any suggestions what am i doing wrong?

Comment: `println("something wrong happened")` this isn't useful, that's why you're struggling, you should be logging the actual exception, so you should be logging `t: Throwable` to know _why_ it failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your JSON response, your list is not of DataRecipies but a list of <DataRecipies.Data>(if your data class follows an inner class model)
so you should change that in the list you're sending to the recycler view.